# Intersection postgis TopologyException

Tags: postgis, topology

I'm trying to make a quite simple analysis in Postgis, but I'm finding some problems. I want to in the first place create buffers for then, intersects themselves but one, this will be differenced. With this product I want to intersects again with another layer. But, here is the problem Postgis complains about a non-existent error topology. I say non-existent because there is no feature in that coordinate.

```
> Error performing intersection: TopologyException: Input geom 1 is
> invalid: Self-intersection at or near point 723120.23091093975
> 4379700.195452339 at 723120.23091093975 4379700.195452339
```

Here is the SQL sentence that I'm using:

```
     select 1 as id, st_intersection(diff_1.st_difference, mapa_ruido_dia.geom)
    from
    (select 1 as id, st_difference(intersectionEMT_valenbisi_carrilBici.st_intersection, buf_ocio.st_union)
    from
    (select 1 as id, st_intersection(buf_carril_bici.st_union,inter_emt_valenbisi.st_intersection)
    from
    (select 1 as id, st_intersection(buf_emt.st_union,buf_valenbisi.st_union)
    from
    (SELECT 1 as id, ST_union(st_buffer(emt_paradas.geom, 200)) FROM emt_paradas )as buf_emt,
    (SELECT 1 as id, ST_union(st_buffer(valenbisi.geom, 200)) FROM valenbisi )as buf_valenbisi) as inter_emt_valenbisi,
    (SELECT 1 as id, ST_union(st_buffer(carril_bici.geom, 200)) FROM carril_bici )as buf_carril_bici) as intersectionEMT_valenbisi_carrilBici,
    (SELECT 1 as id, ST_union(st_buffer(ocio.geom, 250)) FROM ocio )as buf_ocio)as diff_1, mapa_ruido_dia 
     where mapa_ruido_dia.gridcode='1' or mapa_ruido_dia.gridcode='2'
```

Here is the [database](https://mega.co.nz/#!pFgnCBoA!zx-Tb78nPGzL7Fcbw7dMheSbIrMfRJjJ9yV1Qv7Wx6o)

This is the place where postgis says there's a problem,and the two layers I want to intersect

[image: The Yellow star is where I have the topology exception.]

---

**EDIT**:

What I try to do is the next:

1. First I want to create a buffer for emt_paradas, and the layer valenbisi, and then intersect them, the result I will call "intersect_1".
2. Second, I want to create a buffer for carril_bici, and intersect with "intersect_1". The result I will call "intersect_2".
3. Third, I want to create a buffer for layer ocio and make a difference with "intersect_2". The result I will call: "diff_1".
4. Finnaly I want to intersect "diff_1" with layer mapa_ruido_dia, ideally where the field gridcode equals one and two.

Comment: Valencia bike lines, cool, I have used them. Is there any way you could reduce your problem down a bit. It would be useful to know which of the unions, differences or buffers, was causing the problem. In my experience, this kind of error, comes when Linestrings get included as part of some result, so that you end up trying to union or difference a geometry collection with something else -- bad. You can fix this, by using ST_GeometryType and ST_Dump to remove all but (Multi) Polygons.

Comment: Also, what does something like buf_ocio.st_union refer to. It seems like you are using a function name for a non-existent field name.

Comment: John, thank you for your comment. The problem is in the last one. That appears the first, "select 1 as id, st_intersection(diff_1.st_difference, mapa_ruido_dia.geom)" The others are working fine.Linestrings are just used for create the buffer, so I'm working only with polygons. I've started again but the result is the same. Topology exception. I'm going to explicit better what I want to do.

Comment: Sorry, I think the layer mapa_ruido_dia it's a completly mess. Thank you John. :)

Comment: :-). Have you tried running ST_IsValid and/or ST_MakeValid? It is possible that you have an invalid geometry to start with. It is also possible that your queries are creating a Linestring, which could also be the cause of such errors.

Comment: The Postgis list users have suggested that, that's why I know about the mess in the mapa_ruido_dia layer. But what I don't understand how works st_makeValid. I have passed this function in the mess layer, but always gives me the same errors later. Could you explain to me how works exactly? The documentation is a bit confussing for me. Thank you.

Comment: I can't explain to you how it works, but I can attempt to fix the file for you, and then explain what I did. Not because I don't want to, but because I don't fully understand the inner workings, but I am aware of some possible tricks that might help. Can you post the broken file?

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't asking by the inner workings...  I asked for how should I express in postgis to clean the layer. Right now I'm using GRASS (v.clean) to fix this mess (had over 5000 topological errors), right now I'm in 600. The file is this http://mapas.valencia.es/lanzadera/opendata/mapa_ruido_dia/SHAPE (OpenData from Valencia Townhall).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just had a similar problem, and the solution is the following:

1. You have many queries, so the first question is which one of them fails. I'd suggest bisecting the entire SQL query to find where the problem happens exactly. Comment one half of the query (but make it still work) and see if the problem is still there, if so, bisect this half, if not, the error is in the other, bisect that half instead.
2. When you see which particular query fails, check which table has invalid geometries.  My example:

   ```
    with resi as (select st_transform(way, 3857) way from residential),
         road_buff as (select st_buffer(way, 40) way from roads)
    select st_intersection(r.way, b.way) from resi r, road_buff b
    where st_intersects(r.way, b.way)
   ```

   This query failed, and I just looked for which CTE contains invalid geometry:

   ```
    with resi as (select st_transform(way, 3857) way from residential),
         road_buff as (select st_buffer(way, 40) way from roads)
    select r.way, st_isvalid(r.way) val from resi r
   ```

   Then the same for road_buff CTE. Turned out `resi` had invalid geometries. Then I filtered by `val=false`, looked at that table in QGIS, and saw that some polygons were drawn self-intersecting.

[image: Self-intersecting polygons]

The solution was to add `st_makevalid(way)` on that CTE:

```
    with resi as (select st_transform(st_makevalid(way), 3857) way from residential
```

And this solved the issue.

Here's [a good tool](https://github.com/gojuno/lostgis/blob/master/sql/functions/ST_Safe_Repair.sql) to fix different invalid geometries.